# SSIS Get List of all OLE DB Destinations in Data Flow

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, dataflow

I have several SSIS Packages that we use to load in data from multiple different OLE DB data sources into our DB.  Inside each package we have several Data Flow tasks that hold a large amount of OLE DB Sources and Destinations.  What I'm looking to do is see if there is a way to get a text output the holds all of the Destinations flow configurations (Sources would be good to but not top of my list).

I'm trying to make sure that all my OLE DB Destination flows are pointed at the right table, as I've found a few hiccups, without having to double click on each Flow task and check that way, it just becomes tedious and still prone to missing things.

I'm viewing the packages in Visual Studio 2013.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any programmatic ways to discover this data, other than building an application to read the XML within the *.dtsx package. Best advice, pack a lunch and have at it. I know for sure that there is nothing with respect to viewing and setting database tables (only server connections).

Though, a solution I may add once you have determined the list: create a variable(s) to store the unique connection strings and then set those connection strings inside the source/destination components. This will make it easier to manage going forward. In fact, you can take it one step further by setting the same values as parameter, as opposed to variables, which have the added benefit of being exposed on the server. This allows either you or the DBA to set the values as you promote through environments or change server nodes.

Also, I recommend rationalizing that solution into smaller solutions if possible. In my opinion, there is nothing worse than one giant solution that tries to do it all. I am not sure if any of this is helpful, but for what its worth, I do hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SSIS Object Model for your needs..An example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/samskolli/0f757f7148801bd9775f135e2b2dde0b). Look in the method IterateAllDestinationComponentnsInPackage for the exact details. To start understanding the code, start in the Start method and follow the path.

Caveats: Make sure you use the appropriate Monikers and Class IDs for the Data Flow Tasks and your Destination Components. You can also use this for other Control Flow Tasks and Data Flow Components (for example, Source Components as your other need seems to be). Just keep in mind the appropriate Monikers and Class IDs.